# DI и рантайм переменные

Tags: c#, .net-core, di

Допустим, есть класс, пусть это будет какой-то клиент для наглядности. В него нужно передать сервисы, с этим проблем нету, конструктор DI, сервисы всегда одинаковые, все хорошо. Но, в него так же надо передать baseUrl, secret и тд - это рантайм переменные, мы не можем знать их на момент компиляции.

Вариант без DI

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(HttpClientFactory httpFactory, string baseUrl, string secret) {};
    public void PostSmth();
}
```

Использование:

```
var client = new Client(new HttpClientFactory (), "stack.com", "zog");
client.PostSmth();
```

Как быть с DI (коробочный .net core)?
Варианты:

1. Передавать рантайм переменные в методы, а не в конструктор:

   var client = new Client(new HttpClientFactory ());
   client.PostSmth("stack.com", "zog");

Проблема: лишние перемнные во всех публичных методах, для одного инстанса они, в принипе, будут одни и теже.

2. Создать Init метод

```js
    public class Client
    {
        public Client(HttpClientFactory httpFactory) {};
        public void PostSmth();
        public void Init(string baseUrl, string secret) {this.base = baseUrl... }
    }
```

Проблема: инстанс обьекта не есть рабочим без вызова Init.

3. Создать фабрику и спрятать Init там. Проблема: доп сущность "фабрика", свои проблемы с реализацией (я пришел к тому, что использую сервис локатор внутри фарик, но это уже отдельная история)

Option паттерн не подходит, так как это не конфиги, а именно рантайм переменные.
Есть другие варианты? Как быть?

**UPD**

4. И последний вариант - не использовать DI для таких классов, а создавать инстансы вручную.

**UPD 2**

По комментам можно сделать вывод, что фабрики - хорошо.
Какие фабрики тогда использовать?
По [примеру с комментов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37744637/how-can-i-pass-a-runtime-parameter-as-part-of-the-dependency-resolution/37765719#37765719) factory class использует сервис локатор. Так все таки, допустимо ли это? Является ли factory class copposition root-ом? По определению [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277771/what-is-a-composition-root-in-the-context-of-dependency-injection) - нет, ибо это отдельный класс и будет жить далеко от стартапа, например. Так что же остается, только factory method? Или factory class тоже можно использовать?

Comment: нельзя создать синглтон класс `Settings(Provider/Repository/Whatewer)` и инжектить его куда вам надо? Тогда новый `Client` будет брать всегда самые свежие настройки в конструкторе.

Comment: Ещё, в зависимости от типа контейнера. Часто конткейнеры сами поддерживают фабрики и никакого локатора не надо.

Comment: ещё вы скорее всего имеете возиожность передавать значения во время розолва, все боле-менее норм контейнеры позволяют это делать

Comment: ну или инжектить фабрику куда вам надо как `Lazy<Client>` и создавать клента во время использования

Comment: куча вариантов короче, выбирай не хочу. Почитайте книгу Марка Симана - внедренние зависимостей в .NET, прокачаете свой уровень владения DI на пару порядков.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, ни одно из ваших предложений не подходит. Нужны именно рантайм переменные, а не сеттинги. "Выбирай не хочу" - это понятно, но все варианты со своими проблемами, нужно выбрать меньшее зло.

Comment: я не понимаю, что значит "рантайм переменные"? Чем вам [фабрика](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37765719/312041) не подходит?

Comment: @tym32167 например, переменная введенная в форме. Да, в принципе, подходит... Я использовал factory class, но factory method выглядит даже проще.

Comment: для переменной на форме - вы её значение узнаете только в контроллере, то есть у вас нет опции пробросить клиента просто себе в конструктор, вам полюбому надо либо фабрику, либо резолвить клиента ручками (типа service locator). Я больше фабрики уважаю, работа с serviceLocator потом черевата пробросами его везде, где его надо и не надо.

Comment: @tym32167 в factory class в примере выше как раз таки сервис локатор же.  Но там же и ответ "but you are doing that in the composition root", хотя мне все равно не нравиться, что мы вынуждены это делать.

Comment: в том и разница, что на уровне compositionRoot это окей, не окей - это иметь локатор у себя в классах, когда это не обязательно. Локатор позволяет резолвить направо и налево и делает сложным понимание от чего конкретно класс зависит. Но если у вас фабрика. то фабрика может резолвить только что то одно, и с пониманием зависимостей тут окей

Comment: Методы наподобие `Init` - зло. Используйте фабрики! PS: где-то читал, что разработчики Java считают ошибкой создание объектов с помощью `new` и хотят полностью отказаться от него в пользу фабрик.

Comment: @tym32167, отредактировал вопрос, добавив подвопрос, что думаете?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov , отредактировал вопрос, добавив подвопрос, что думаете?

Comment: почему никто не рассматривает вариант с IOptions<T> ?

Answer (score 0):

На мой субъективный взгляд первый вариант является самым честным. Потому что он дествительно отображает реальный интерфейс нашей операции и динамичность параметров. Поясню ниже с примерами требований чтобы показать различия.

- выкачивать картинку с любого сайта с которого укажет пользователь;
- выкачивать любую картинку с сайта который указан в конфиге;
- выкачивать любую картинку с сайта который указан в конфиге и иметь возможность динамически менять урл сайта в конфиге;

Для этих трех случаях я вижу два варианта реализации. Первый он динамичен и тут передача в метод на мой взгляд правильное решение. Вторые два решаются с помощью инжекции в конструктор.

Я иногда смотрю на это с такой перспективы. Partial application в ФП мире это тоже самое что внедрение зависимостей в объектом мире. То есть если нам надо запомнить аргументы и дальше использовать объект в нескольких местах с этими же аргументами значит они подлежат инжекции в конструктор например и в момент резолва контролера можно вычитывать их из конфига, даже если сам конфиг может динамически меняться, только меняется время жизни этого класса. Другой вариант когда например вам пришел на вход массив урлов откуда надо выкачать картинки это аргумент операции и инжектировать в конструктор не особо полезно так как реализация такого пользовательского сценария усложнится. В первую очередь надо смотреть на требования и как они будут реализованы в коде, а не пытаться свести все к ижектированию. А если очень хочется то у Марка Симана в книге есть глава с примером внедрение в метод. Мне кажется это очень похоже.

Последнее что хочется добавить, я бы учел то как много будет создаваться Client-ов и как возможно обслуживать максимальное количество операции с минимальным количеством HttpClient.